# Assigning an int value to string in an array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I need to add prices for an array of items that the user wishes to purchase, say a book bag is equal to $40, that way I can add up the values and find a total. I am also having trouble with the int parsing. It throws a java main exception.  I've looked online but I can't find any good information.

Here is the relevant sections of my code:

```
// Output items available for purchase 
    String[] csuStore = {"bookbag", "textbook", "notebook", "pen", "pencil", "sweatpants", "shirt", "sweater", "candy", "planner"};
    System.out.println("Textbook:     $50");
    System.out.println("Bookbag:      $40");
    System.out.println("Sweatpants:   $35");
    System.out.println("Sweater:      $30");
    System.out.println("Shirt:        $25");
    System.out.println("Planner:      $15");
    System.out.println("Notebook:     $3");
    System.out.println("Candy:        $2");
    System.out.println("Pen:          $1");
    System.out.println("Pencil:       $1");

    // Ask how many items the customer would like to purchase. 
    System.out.print("Enter how many items you would like to purchase: ");
    int items = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    if (items == 0) {
        System.out.println("Have a great day, come again soon!");
    if (items > 10)
        System.out.println("You're buying too much! Please decide on less than 10 items.");
    }

    // Have user to enter names of items they would like to purchase
        String arrayOfItems[] = new String[items];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of item #" + (i+1) + " : ");
                arrayOfItems[i] = input.nextLine();
        }       
        //Items purchased
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Items being purchased " + (i+1) + " : ");
                System.out.print(arrayOfItems[i] + "\n");
        }
```

Comment: Hint: Make a class that represents an item with properties for description and price. Then create a bunch of those in an array as your items for sale.

Comment: as above said, use OOP concept should make things much easier. Try using `input.nextInt()` instead of `input.nextLine()` and wrap around with `try catch`

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1. Use `Scanner` class to take input. Scanner has bunch of useful methods e.g. nextInt() and you dont have to parse string to int or think of newline/space etc.
2. Now regarding to your question: how to handle price of the book

   a. Have one more array for proce and now you will have one to one relationship with two lists.

   b. Just have a map with bookname as key and prices as value...

   c. As others said, create a class :

   ```
   class Book {
     String name;
     Double price;
   }
   ```

   Now your books will look like this

   ```
   List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
3. I would advise reading more documentation/Java material.

Answer (score 0):

May be below code could help you. But I recommend to use OOPs concept of class and objects for better result and easy modifications in functionality.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class demoClass {
public static void main(String[] args){

 int total=0;
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
// Output items available for purchase 
String[][] csuStore = {{"bookbag","40"},
                        {"textbook","30"},
                        {"notebook","20"}, 
                        {"pen","10"}};
System.out.println("1. Textbook:     $30");
System.out.println("2. Bookbag:      $40");
System.out.println("3. Notebook:     $20");
System.out.println("4. Pen:          $10");

// Ask how many items the customer would like to purchase. 
System.out.print("Enter how many items you would like to purchase: ");
int items = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
if (items == 0) {
    System.out.println("Have a great day, come again soon!");
if (items > 10)
    System.out.println("You're buying too much! Please decide on less than 10 items.");
}

// Have user to enter names of items they would like to purchase
    String arrayOfItems[] = new String[items];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the name of item #" + (i+1) + " : ");
            arrayOfItems[i] = input.nextLine();
            for (int j=0; j<csuStore.length ;j++){
                if(arrayOfItems[i].equalsIgnoreCase(csuStore[j][0])){
                    total=total+Integer.parseInt(csuStore[j][1]);
                }
            }
    }       
    //Items purchased
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Items being purchased " + (i+1) + " : ");
            System.out.print(arrayOfItems[i] + "\n");

    }
    System.out.print("Total Amount:::: " + total);
  }
  }
```

You can also use for loop to display list of items instead of System.out.print every time.